# Solving an equation set with n equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Here's the exercise I'm doing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucLt0.png

$$
\begin{cases}
x_ 1 &+& x_2 & & & &&& = 1 \\
     &&  x_2  &+& x_3 &&&& = 3 \\
     && && x_3 &+& x_4 && = 5 \\
     &&&&&&& \ddots & \vdots  \\
     &&&&&&& x_{n-1} + x_n &= 2n-3 \\
2x_1 &+& &&&&&x_n &= 2n-1 
\end{cases}
$$

Translation:
Let n be any natural number. Consider the following system of n equations with n variables:

a) solve the system assuming that n is even. Hint: add all oddly numbered equations to the first equation and then subtract all evenly numbered equations. Then the first and the last equations will make a system with two identical variables
B) Doing something similar to a) solve the system assuming that n is odd

So far, I've come up with two different solutions, one per subexercise: https://ufile.io/ac97oagy. Raw latex [here](https://pastebin.com/PVvj6zWp) if you prefer it that way.

Why do I think that the solutions are wrong:
a) $x_n$ being constant seems off, just like $x_1$ being dependent on n. The math on this looks sound, but it still ticks me off
b) Both $x_n$ and $x_1$ depend on n. That is weird. I also can't really explain why the sum of half of all the equations is $n(n - 3) / 2$.

I asked a few friends for help, but they all come up with different results. I'd appreciate if someone could point out holes in my logic.

Comment: You can try plugging in your obtained value of $x_1$ into the system, then  solving for the other $x_{k}$  until you get you get $x_{n}$ (which you will at the penultimate equation). Then check if the $x_{n}$ and the final remaining equation agree on your values. If so, then your solution is correct. Eg: for even $n$ you got $x_1=n$ , which implies $x_2 = 1-n$, $x_3 = 2 + n \dots$.

Comment: After doing that, a) was solved correctly. I'll try solving b) in the same way